# Solving simple modulus with a variable but use inegality operator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is very simple but my brain forgot some theory for 5-6 years. Please help me

I have this simple `|4x-2| >= -1`

Sorry if I took your time for explanation.

Thank you

Comment: This is definitely not a question about modules. Perhaps you refer to $|\cdot |$ as *modulus*? Also, the inequality you give is true for all $x$, since $|\cdot |$ always gives a nonnegative number.

Comment: @AlexBecker: True, sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

All $x$ numbers are solutions, since $|z| \ge 0$ for any (real or complex) number, and $0\ge -1$ and $\ge$ is transitive.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'module' is a mistranslation into English from your native language. This is an inequality which is true for any $x$, because absolute value always returns a nonnegative number.

Comment: I got it but I neeed to calculate the `x` . I corrected the title

Comment: Sure. But $x$ can be any complex number and your inequality will still be satisfied. There are infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to solve it, in the case where not all $x$'s are solutions. Say you had to solve $x$ such that
$$
|4x-2|\leq 1.
$$
What $| x |\leq n$ means is that $x$ is comprised between $-n$ and $n$, and so you have $-n\leq x\leq n$. In your (my) case, it would become
\begin{array}{rll}
-1\leq& 4x-2&\leq 1 \\
1\leq& 4x&\leq 3\\
\frac{1}{4}\leq& x&\leq \frac{3}{4}
\end{array}
so for $\geq$ inequality, you take the complement of that set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I don't know if you meant $1$ or $-1$, but in any case $|4x-2| \ge 1$ is equivalent to $4x-2 \le -1$ or $4x-2 \ge 1$.

Comment: for some reason I did the case $|4x-2|\leq 1$